# Javascript comma syntax

Tags: javascript

Why do so many developers write commas this way?

```
var npm = module.exports = new EventEmitter
  , config = require("./lib/config")
  , set = require("./lib/utils/set");
```

Not this way?

```
var npm = module.exports = new EventEmitter,
    config = require("./lib/config"),
    set = require("./lib/utils/set");
```

Comment: Many? Do you have any concrete stats/evidence?

Comment: @BalusC: Does s/he need "concrete stats" to ask such a question? Anyone who's spent a couple months in JS world has seen this pattern somewhere, in a library or in a coworker's code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They write them with the "," at the beginning of the line to make it easier to maintain the code (add lines or remove/comment out lines).

Given this:

```
var npm = module.exports = new EventEmitter
  , config = require("./lib/config")
  , set = require("./lib/utils/set");
```

It's much cleaner and easier to do this:

```
var npm = module.exports = new EventEmitter
//  , config = require("./lib/config")
  , set = require("./lib/utils/set");
```

as well as add new lines like this:

```
var npm = module.exports = new EventEmitter
  , config = require("./lib/config")
  , anothervalue = require("./lib/aval")
  , anothervalue2 = require("./lib/aval2")
  , set = require("./lib/utils/set");
```

Comment: I don't see any reason the comma at the start would make either of those easier compared to the comma at the end?

Comment: This is just style, nothing more, if it takes you to long to comment out a line... switch your editor but don't write such (IMO, remember it's about style) code.

Comment: This really becomes more of an advantage when you're working on much longer objects / functions... With 3 or 4 lines, it really doesn't make of difference, but with an object with 30 or 40 attributes that have to be maintained periodically, it becomes very advantageous.

Comment: I don't personally use this style but the answer does a good job of explaining its use - one benefit that follows from it is that you are only editing the lines you actually wrote; a version control system's annotate function would not claim that you wrote a line that you simply appended a comma to.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion over the years and came across node.js narg module which had this syntax and I was pleasantly surprised. I have thought I was an alien when doing this but glad to see others have come to the same conclusion :) IMO Software is its own language and there is no sense in constraining any code to the rules of the English language.

Comment: FYI - The same technique can be used effectively to concatenate strings where the + would be placed at the beginning instead of the end. I have found this effective in both cases. Also, StringBuffer in Java where you put ).append( at the beginning of the line. I guess the same could be done in many other chaining based api's.

Answer (score 1):

I never saw that pattern before in JS, so I'm not sure if there are *that many* developers that use it, but I would guess they do that so variable names are aligned,  to emphasize that `var` actually defines three variables in your sample code.

If that's the case however, it would be clearer (and less weird) to just use `var` three times:

```
var npm = module.exports = new EventEmitter;
var config = require("./lib/config");
var set = require("./lib/utils/set");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is strictly a programmer-specific syntaxtual preference. I know a lot of DBA's that sem to prefer that method, while I prefer the trailing comma myself. there's nor real difference except for personal preference/education.

Answer (score 0):

`var npm = module.exports = new EventEmitter

config = require("./lib/config") // ,

//anothervalue = require("./lib/aval"),

//anothervalue2 = require("./lib/aval2"),

set = require("./lib/utils/set");` 


See the extra "//"... you would have to add the "//" to an existing line at the end as well as add it to the next line...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:** The above question prompted me to scratch an itch that has bothered me for some time. After quite a bit of rumination, I have come up with a good justification for leading commas: easily spot missing commas. This is a potentially nasty source of bugs, since, rather than complain, the compiler will simply add a semicolon, thus changing the meaning quite dramatically:

```
var a = foo(),
    b = bar()  // Oops...
    c = baz(); // Ouch!
```

The third line no longer initialises a new variable in the current scope. It assigns to an existing variable in an outer scope or initializes a new global variable if there isn't one.

This doesn't explain the use of leading commas in JSON. Perhaps it just carried over by fiat.

That said, I still favour separate declarations, which make it all simple and safe.

I'll leave my rant in place for posterity.

---

I agree that it appears all over the place. Almost every second library I peruse uses this convention. Frankly, I don't get it.

Trailing commas make it awkward to comment out the last line of a group...

```
var //a = foo(), easy
    b = bar(),
    c = baz();

var a = foo(),
    b = bar()/*, awkward
    c = baz()*/;
```

...whereas leading commas make it awkward for both the first and last line...

```
var /*a = foo() awkward
  , */b = bar()
  , c = baz();

var a = foo()
  , b = bar()/* awkward
  , c = baz()*/;
```

This is progress?

(One could of course win a cheap point by observing that semicolons are optional, but this only achieves parity at the expense of shunning best-practice.)

Worse, leading commas are also used for JSON. Here's a package.json generated by Express.

```
{
    "name": "application-name"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": "2.5.10"
    , "jade"   : ">= 0.0.1"
  }
}
```

This is a PITA because most editors don't like indenting sibling lines differently to each other. Note that the first line of a group is indented more than the following lines.

The use of leading commas strikes me as a pointless affectation that causes problems without solving any. The only argument I can think of that has any merit is that leading commas line up with each other; not very compelling.

Fortunately, CoffeeScript is taking over the world, which renders the question moot (it even trounces JSON for config).

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I don't actually favour trailing commas for the above scenario. I think declaring individual vars makes the most sense. It's clean, regular and makes it very easy to comment out individual items.

```
var a = foo();
var b = bar();
var c = baz();
```